# Execute a stored procedure from python

Tags: python, sql, db2

I wanted to run a DB2 (IBM i) stored procedure using python

My connection with DB2 was successful using pyodbc.

My script looks like this:

```
import json
import pyodbc

with open("config.json","r") as f:
    CONFIG = json.load(f)

dsn = CONFIG["servername"]["dsn"]
schema= CONFIG["servername"]["schema"]
tbl= CONFIG["servername"]["tbl"]
sp = CONFIG["servername"]["sp"]
user = CONFIG["servername"]["user"]
pw = CONFIG["servername"]["pw"]

conn = pyodbc.connect(f"DSN={dsn};UID={user};PWD={pw}")
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Now, when I try to run the SP using the script below:

```
test_query = f"""CALL MYLIB.MYSP()"""
cursor.execute(test_query)

--or something like this
--test_query = f"""CALL {schema}.{tbl}()"""
--cursor.execute(test_query)
```

I encountered this error:
Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [IBM][iSeries Access ODBC Driver][DB2 UDB]SQL0440 - Routine MYSP in MYLIB not found with specified parameters. (-440) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Note: My SP creates a table. I execute this SP from DBeaver using the command:
CALL MYLIB.MYSP();

Answer (score 0):

Noob mistake. I resolved the issue by using the correct credentials I used to create the SP.